I want one column of Panadas dataframe which is a URL and which I save as CSV to be directly clickable
I want to write this data frame to csv file where column B is shown as clickable link in Excel on the first go and not clicking it with enter. Following code should have worked but I still  donot get a underlined clickable hyperlink in Excel csv file.
def main():
    pass

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import io
    import sys

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B"])
    df.at[0, 'A'] =  "Link1"
    df.at[0, 'B'] =  "https://nseindia.com"

    def make_clickable(val):
    df.style.format({'B': make_clickable})

    print(df)

#now I want to write this to csv file where column B is shown as clickable link in ExceL
with open('C:\\dropbox\\apy\\test.csv', "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
df.to_csv(f, index=False, lineterminator='\n')
f.close()


I could solve it like this
df.loc[(df.B!= ""),'B']= '=HYPERLINK("'+ df['B']+ '")'


The make_clickable is defined to format the URL as a clickable hyperlink. It uses the Excel HYPERLINK function.
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(make_clickable) help to convert all column data to hyperlink.
import pandas as pd

def make_clickable(url):
    return f'=HYPERLINK("{url}", "{url}")'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {
        "A": ["Link1", "Link2", "Link3"],
        "B": ["https://google.com", "https://facebook.com", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78285294/i-want-one-column-of-panadas-dataframe-which-is-a-url-and-which-i-save-as-csv-to"]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    df['B'] = df['B'].apply(make_clickable)

    with open('test.csv', "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, index=False, line_terminator='\n')

I have tested with creating dummy df it worked.
